# Stripe - How to use react-stripe to create accounts that can accept payments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am working on a stripe backend, using node as my backend and react as my frontend. As I am looking to build a platform I plan to allow users who will receive payments to set up their own accounts. I need to handle PII, Initially I had a form and sent data straight to my node server to create tokens like so:

```
//CREATE ACCOUNT TOKEN WITH SENSITIVE INDIVIDUAL INFORMATION
app.post("/makeAccountToken", cors(), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const token = await stripe.tokens.create({
            account: {
              business_type: 'individual',
              individual: {
                id_number: '000000000',
                first_name: 'Jane',
                last_name: 'Doe',
                ssn_last_4: '0000',
              },
              tos_shown_and_accepted: true,
            }
          });
          res.send(token);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400)
        res.send({ error: err })
        return;
    }
});
```

**My understanding is this is not secure and that my client application should create a token which is sent to the backend to create an account.** But from what I am seeing [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens) this is only in straight javascript. I checked the [react-stripe](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js) library but don't see anything on generating tokens for account creation. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Not looking for a full code answer so much as guidance to an example or basic concept of how one would do this.

Or is using a node server to communicate these details to stripe's api fine?

**EDIT: My current process**

Adding for reference:

React sends sensitive data (account numbers and ssn etc) to my node server -->

`stripe.tokens.create` in my node server produces a token -->

token is passed to `stripe.accounts.create` in node and creates the account and onboarding finishes with some extra info if need be

Comment: I would say it's fine to use Stripe's nodejs client to do that. The nodejs client needs the private api key to your stripe account and then it can call https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

Comment: You cannot create Stripe accounts on the frontend. It has to be done on the backend.

Comment: Yeah I understand the creation of accounts is on the backend, but I mean the tokenization process. Is it secure to pass form data via a post call to back end, get it tokenized and then pass it to the account creation process?